# ORA-00904: invalid identifier Error while making foreign key in the Sales_Invoice table

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Car (Car_ID int PRIMARY KEY,
Serial_Number int, Make VARCHAR(255),
Model VARCHAR(255), Colour VARCHAR(255),
Year int, Car_for_Sale_Y_N VARCHAR (25));   


CREATE TABLE Salesperson 
(Salesperson_ID int primary KEY, 
Last_Name VARCHAR (255), 
First_Name VARCHAR (255));

    
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(Customer_ID int PRIMARY KEY, 
Last_Name VARCHAR (255),
First_Name VARCHAR(255), 
Phone_Number VARCHAR(255), 
Address VARCHAR (255), 
City VARCHAR(255), 
STATE_PROVINCE VARCHAR (255), 
Country VARCHAR (255), 
Postal_Code VARCHAR (255));

    
CREATE TABLE Sales_Invoice 
(Invoice_ID int PRIMARY KEY, Invoice_Number VARCHAR (255), 
Date DATE, 
Car_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Car(Car_ID), 
Customer_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID));
```

Output: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Please help what's wrong here its not working. In the Sales_invoice table when I create the foreign keys it shows that error what is the problem.

Comment: Please only tag a single RDBMS - not 3! Oracle errors are specific to Oracle, they are not shared with other databases.

Comment: Rename field "Date" to something else and check it again!

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions, if I may.

- don't use `varchar`, but `varchar2` datatype. Why? Oracle recommends so

  - you aren't one of my colleagues in disguise, are you? Their `varchar2` columns are all `(255)`, so that they are sure that most of information they put in there will fit. But, do you *really* need that? Postal code whose length is 255 characters? Come one, be serious!
- name all your constraints. If you don't Oracle will create default name which looks like `SYS_C007858` and you'll have no idea what it really is. But, if its name is e.g. `pk_car`, you'll know that it is a primary key on the `car` table
- as commented, `date` is reserved for datatype, you can't use it as a column name (OK, you *can* if you enclose it into double quotes, but you shouldn't)

Finally:

```
SQL> create table car
  2    (car_id           int constraint pk_car primary key,
  3     serial_number    int,
  4     make             varchar2(255),
  5     model            varchar2(255),
  6     colour           varchar2(255),
  7     year             int,
  8     car_for_sale_y_n varchar2 (25));

Table created.

SQL> create table salesperson
  2  (salesperson_id int constraint pk_salesper primary key,
  3   last_name      varchar2(255),
  4   first_name     varchar2(255));

Table created.

SQL> create table customer
  2  (customer_id    int constraint pk_cust primary key,
  3   last_name      varchar2 (255),
  4   first_name     varchar2(255),
  5   phone_number   varchar2(255),
  6   address        varchar2(255),
  7   city           varchar2(255),
  8   state_province varchar2(255),
  9   country        varchar2(255),
 10   postal_code    varchar2(255));

Table created.

SQL> create table sales_invoice
  2  (invoice_id     int constraint pk_salinv primary key,
  3   invoice_number varchar2 (255),
  4   datum          date,
  5   car_id         int constraint fk_salinv_car references car(car_id),
  6   customer_id    int constraint fk_salinv_cust references customer(customer_id));

Table created.

SQL>
```